# Integrating ccavenue payment integration with laravel and angular 7

Tags: angular, laravel, payment-gateway, ccavenue

Hi I was looking for a guide to integrate ccavenue payment gateway with my angular app which uses laravel as backend. Found this link

https://medium.com/@daveinside/integrating-ccavenue-in-node-js-angular-5-b9de44091062

But I am confused with the service part that is used to get encryption data. What kind of encryption or code is needed from this service.

```
this.checkoutService.getEnc(this.orderInformation).subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.encRequest = response.encRequest;
  setTimeout(_ => this.form.nativeElement.submit());
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Want to know about checkout service like what information and how to encrypt the data.

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, Here is what I implemented in my application.

First import **of** from **rxjs**

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Now, implement **getEnc** function like this.

```
getEnc(formData: any) {
    const nodeCCAvenue = require("node-ccavenue")
    const ccav = new nodeCCAvenue.Configure({
      merchant_id: '[Your Merchant ID]',
      working_key: '[Your Working Key]'
    });
    const encryptedData = ccav.getEncryptedOrder(formData);
    return of({encRequest : encryptedData});     
}
```

If you get script error saying 'global' is undefined,

Add the following three lines in polyfill.ts at the end.

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
global.process = require('process');
```

NP: I am using Angular 9 and I hope this works for Angular 7 as well.

Comment: Is it safe to put merchant key and working key with angular or should one use  a server to handle this

Comment: You should use it in your api / server side not on angular side.